# "Divulge" vs "Disclose" v "Reveal" vs "Unveil" the story of

Tags: word-choice

I was wondering which choice below sounds more idiomatic in my sentence:

> - They massacred many people and then security and intelligence forces threatened victims’ families with arrest if they.............their loved ones to international news media.

**a. disclose** the story of 
**b. divulge** the story of 
**c. reveal** the story of 
**d. unveil** the story of

I think they all work here with a very slight nuance in their shades of meaning.

[Disclose](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/disclose): to make something known publicly, or to show something that was hidden. 
[Divulge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/divulge): to make something secret known. 
[Reveal](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/reveal): to make known or show something that is surprising or that was previously secret. 
[Unveil](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unveil): to make something secret known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this [GNgram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=reveal%20to%20the%20press%2Cdisclose%20to%20the%20press%2Cunveil%20to%20the%20press%2Cdivulge%20to%20the%20press&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Creveal%20to%20the%20press%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdisclose%20to%20the%20press%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdivulge%20to%20the%20press%3B%2Cc0) shows, I wouldn't use ***unveil***. This verb is not commonly used with an indirect object, you can unveil things but you don't commonly say ***to whom***. At best, you could unveil something ***before*** someone.

The GNgram also shows how commonly each verb is used. ***Reveal*** (rather neutral) has the upper hand, but this is not because ***divulge*** or ***disclose*** are less correct, but because they are more technical and accurate for *revealing something that should not be revealed*, and therefore more restricted in meaning and use. They are also both very formal. Whichever you choose is a matter of preference.

Comment: I found " A memorial has been unveiled to a dolphin which became a local celebrity off the Dorset coast" in a [BBC report](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-dorset-58375409), which I think could have done with some better editing.